# How Detect Intel Graphic Processor?

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, hybrid-graphics

My laptop has a nvidia 425 geforce video card!

I'm keen on to find wether my laptop has another(intel) graphic processor or not?

and so, enable Intel Integrated for usage!

How should i find this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To know complete information about your graphics card we have two useful methods.open your terminal and type

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

sample outputs:

```
raja@badfox:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
raja@badfox:~$
```

and one more thing:

```
sudo lshw -C video
```

sample output for example

```
raja@badfox:~$ sudo lshw -C video
  *-display:0             
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:45 memory:fd800000-fdbfffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:ff00(size=8)
  *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fde00000-fdefffff
raja@badfox:~$
```

Hope that helps,:) .

Comment: this is Output:

milad@Miladsob ~ % lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 425M] (rev a1)

Comment: how should i enable intel Integrated Graphic card?

Comment: if you have Intel graphic card then you can . but as you gave the output there is no Intel VGA in your PC.

Comment: If it does not show up at `lspci`, it does not mean that the hardware is not capable of it. See [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/178537/6969)

Answer (score 5):

To list all display adapters you should use the below command:

```
lspci -nn | grep '\[03[02]0\]'
```

This searches for the "VGA compatible controller", but also "3D controller" (which is how some Nvidia cards are exposed). Example output for my hybrid graphics laptop (i5-460m and GT 425M):

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 02)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 425M] [10de:0df0] (rev a1)
```

If your machine has an integrated Intel video card, but it does not show up, consider looking in the BIOS settings. Vendors like Lenovo provide you an option to select between an Intel-only, Nvidia-only or hybrid Intel/Nvidia setup. Selecting the Intel-only or Nvidia-only modes will effectively hide the adapters from the `lspci` output.

Comment: Thank you @Lekensteyn, but i have Sony VAIO and the Vendor didn't provide an option like that you say!

i entered the command you recommended it, But the result was same as previous command!

Comment: I missed it first time round because the single-adapter setting is called 'Auto' in my bios. How confusing! Thanks for prompting me to look again.