# Intel Graphics card not seen by ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

As title says. I am running on a dual boot laptop with Windows 10 too.

I have an [Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz × 8](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/97185/intel-core-i7-7700hq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-80-ghz.html) on my machine and a GTX 1070 Nvidia GPU, but I can not make Ubuntu see the Intel driver that comes with the CPU. I have a manually installed NVIDIA driver running on that (the latest that comes with CUDA 10.2).

I tried:

- Installing mesa-utils. [Intel HD Graphics card not recognized in System Info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73074/intel-hd-graphics-card-not-recognized-in-system-info)
- `lspci` and its multiple `grep` options (and with none). Only the Nvidia GPU is visible. [How do I find out the model of my graphics card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72766/how-do-i-find-out-the-model-of-my-graphics-card), 
  [How Detect Intel Graphic Processor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178527/how-detect-intel-graphic-processor), [How do I get Ubuntu to detect my Intel Graphics?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/713326/how-do-i-get-ubuntu-to-detect-my-intel-graphics)
- Checking updates for drivers, but if the hardware is not seen, the drivers neither. [Ubuntu 13.10 64bit does not detect intel graphic card!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368868/ubuntu-13-10-64bit-does-not-detect-intel-graphic-card)

What else can I try?

Info:

```
$ spci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'; uname -a 


01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104M [GeForce GTX 1070 Mobile] (rev a1)     
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GP104M [GeForce GTX 1070 Mobile]   
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia    
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia 

Linux Ander 5.3.0-28-generic #30~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 17 06:14:09 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

```
$ lscpu

Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              8
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-7
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               158
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
Stepping:            9
CPU MHz:             900.048
CPU max MHz:         3800,0000
CPU min MHz:         800,0000
BogoMIPS:            5599.85
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-7
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d
```

Comment: 1. Ubuntu 18.10 is EoL. 2. Not all Intel CPU's have a built-in GPU.

Comment: @Pilot6 actually its 18.04, I made a mistake. Not sure if that makes a difference. 1) yup, I know it is, but I can not make my collaborators change the version so I need to work there. 2)Yes, I know. This is why I showed a link to my CPU showing that it has one

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'; uname -a` terminal command.

Comment: It looks like kernel doesn't support this adapter, or it is disabled in BIOS, or the CPU doesn't have it. Recently I installed an Intel CPU and was surprised that it didn't have a GPU.

Comment: What does `lscpu` show?

Comment: @Pilot6 hum maybe the BIOS has it disabled? Certainly it exists, as 1)the model has it 2) I can see it in windows. `lscpu` shows a large output, what are you particularly interested in?

Comment: @Pilot6 https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/97185/intel-core-i7-7700hq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-80-ghz.html shows this CPU has Intel HD Graphics 630.

Answer (score 2):

I have Lenovo Legion Y540 and I faced the same problem. To fix this there was a option in my BIOS to change from discrete graphic to switchable graphics and that the did the trick for me.