# Dell Inspiron 11 3147 only boots via safe mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, graphics, dell, inspiron

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 (alongside Windows 10) on my laptop, and it booted well and fine the first time, but when I booted it later, it got hung up at a text screen (before the ubuntu splash) and did not boot.

Then I selected safe mode, then resume normal boot, and it only boots that way.

It also is a bit jittery moving windows around, which it shouldn't be.

Another (very minor) thing is that the windows button on the monitor doesn't work.

Could any of you guys help?

---

My system specs are below:

RAM: 4 GiBs

HDD: 500 GiBs

CPU: Intel® Pentium(R) CPU N3530 @ 2.16GHz × 4

GPU: (this may be the problem here as ubuntu identifies it as "unknown") Intel HD Graphics 4000

Screen Resolution: 1366x768

---

lspci -vv results:

https://pastebin.com/5FfKQ9Zt

---

inxi -G results:

Card: Intel Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display

```
       Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 )

       drivers: fbdev (unloaded: modesetting,vesa)

       Resolution: 1366x768@76.00hz

       OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 128 bits)

       version: 3.3 Mesa 20.0.8
```

I have also tried a solution to a very simular problem here:

[Intel Graphics card not seen by ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208772/intel-graphics-card-not-seen-by-ubuntu-18-04?rq=1)

But I don't have that option in the UEFI screen.

Comment: Yes this is the problem. For some unknown reasons you don't have any Intel drivers -why does not make sense - because HD Graphics is supported. What you could do: When "Grub" (the bootloader) shows up add the kernel property `--nomodeset` using the "edit" feature of grub. This is not permanent - but could help you to enter your OS. On sucess open a terminal and enter 'lspci -vv` and copy the contents into your question. With `inxi` installed please output `inxi -G` as well

Comment: @kanehekili I just updated the question with the outputs of the two cmds.

Comment: Is there any way I can manually install the Intel HD Graphics drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple hours of searching, I found a solution:
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core`

After a reboot it now boots normally and, displays graphics card as:
Intel® HD Graphics (BYT)!

Comment: Great!. Question is- why wasn't it there in the first place? I'm using the same drivers and never had to reinstall them...

Comment: i dunno, that's the strange thing